# IPhone TextView hidden by keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextView` editable when selected appears the keyboard. The problem is that when the text is so big he gets behind the keyboard. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should scroll the view up when KeyBoard is appearing. Use this tutorial to achieve it http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your view up by this code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  //change origin y 
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-150,320,436)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   //reset origin y 
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,436)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

set x and y value according your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

change base view size when edit UITextField,decrease base view orgin origin y to edit text field

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  //change origin y 
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   //reset origin y 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate methods of `UITextfield`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
            //change origin y 
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(X,newY,width,height)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
            //reset origin y 
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(X,Y,width,height)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Don't forget to set the UITextFieldDelegate in your ".h" file and the appropriate text fileds `textfiled.delegate = self`.